# Html table with nested table and header

Tags: html

I am trying to build complex html table with nested table and headers in main table that will fit nested table, so far I've got:

```css
.module-table {
    border: solid thin;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.module-table th {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid thin;
}

.module-table-cell {
    border: solid thin;
}
```

```html
   <table class="module-table module-table-info">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">
            ID: 0
        </th>
        <th colspan="2">Modules</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Slot No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="module-table-rack-info">
            Row: 0<br>
            Type: Unknown Type
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">1</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">Y4BO94QZ17Y3I8</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">3</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">RXAL1YSRA0FNWT</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">5</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">OFV2FZJE6OCTR0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">7</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">VMNO0XD5GNI5K3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">9</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">M9M5TWUVBY12XR</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">13</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">TDWDOOFVD7CD7K</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">15</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">MUY6FNX60KK68C</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="module-table-rack-info">
            Row: 1<br>
            Type: Unknown Type
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">1</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">Y4BO94QZ17Y3I8</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">3</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">RXAL1YSRA0FNWT</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">5</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">OFV2FZJE6OCTR0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">7</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">VMNO0XD5GNI5K3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">9</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">M9M5TWUVBY12XR</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">13</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">TDWDOOFVD7CD7K</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">15</td>
                        <td class="module-table-cell">MUY6FNX60KK68C</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now as you see nested table does not fit into space where Id like it to be.

What I am trying to do is to fit that nested table under Slot No. and Name header so far no luck, any suggestions?

EDIT:

Using @Quentin suggestion Ive fixed table with popper html tags, but how to make headers fit nested table?

Comment: child table inside of parent table > td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<tr>` can have as its children **only** `<th>` and `<td>` elements.

If you want to put another table there it needs to be inside one of those.

(You probably *shouldn't* be involving another table anyway, and expressing the relationship between data using `rowspan` and `colspan`, but I've no idea what the relationship between your bits of data is supposed to be).

Comment: Aye I have added suggested changes, but is there any way to fix headers of main table so that they would fit nested table.

Comment: @WojciechSzabowicz — See the last paragraph of this answer; nested tables are the wrong solution to your problem.

Comment: I played around with colspan and rowspan and Ive got it as it should be, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.module-table {
    border: solid thin;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.module-table th {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid thin;
}

.module-table-cell {
    border: solid thin;
}
.module-table tbody:nth-of-type(odd){
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.module-table-rack-info{
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="module-table module-table-info">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">
        ID: 0
      </th>
      <th colspan="2">Modules</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Slot No.</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-rack-info" rowspan="8">
        Row: 0
      </td>
    </tr>
    <td class="module-table-cell">1</td>
    <td class="module-table-cell">Y4BO94QZ17Y3I8</td>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">3</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">RXAL1YSRA0FNWT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">5</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">OFV2FZJE6OCTR0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">7</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">VMNO0XD5GNI5K3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">9</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">M9M5TWUVBY12XR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">13</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">TDWDOOFVD7CD7K</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">15</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">MUY6FNX60KK68C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-rack-info" rowspan="8">
        Row: 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">1</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">Y4BO94QZ17Y3I8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">3</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">RXAL1YSRA0FNWT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">5</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">OFV2FZJE6OCTR0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">7</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">VMNO0XD5GNI5K3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">9</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">M9M5TWUVBY12XR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">13</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">TDWDOOFVD7CD7K</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">15</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">MUY6FNX60KK68C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-rack-info" rowspan="8">
        Row: 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <td class="module-table-cell">1</td>
    <td class="module-table-cell">Y4BO94QZ17Y3I8</td>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">3</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">RXAL1YSRA0FNWT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">5</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">OFV2FZJE6OCTR0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">7</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">VMNO0XD5GNI5K3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">9</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">M9M5TWUVBY12XR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">13</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">TDWDOOFVD7CD7K</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="module-table-cell">15</td>
      <td class="module-table-cell">MUY6FNX60KK68C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```